# Is there any option to revert an applied diff (or patch) without affecting local changes?

Tags: git, gerrit

I have applied a diff (patch) to my code and I have made my local changes to it.Now I found that the diff applied is not needed for me so I have to revert the diff without affecting my local changes.Provide me a solution please

I have tried using `git apply -R<filename.diff` but it doesn't apply as i have made changes to the same file where diff is applied.

Comment: And when you run `git apply -R`, what happens? Perhaps provide the output of the run?

Comment: Hmm.... you might have to fall back to using `patch` to remove that patch (and deal with the conflicts). I truly hope you have save the state of the working tree with either a revision or stashing it before attempting to run experiments.

Comment: Does doing this prevents my local changes unaffected and reverts only the applied diff?

Comment: upon using git apply -R<file.diff I was able to revert the diff but few changes made near to the diff index cannot be reversed

Comment: You better commit your local changes, then use `git rebase -i` to go back and remove or adjust the bogous commit. (All the warnings about publishing rewritten history apply.)

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to stash your local changes, then apply the patch, then re-apply your local changes from the stash.

Generally you can preserve your changes in a stash (while temporarily getting them 'out of they way" - i.e. out of the worktree and index) by saying

```
git stash
```

(If you find you also need to stash untracked files, yo uwould use `git stash -u`.)

Once your worktree and index are in a clean state, you can apply the patch normally.

Then you can re-apply the changes to your worktree with

```
git stash pop
```

If, when you created the stash, some changes were staged and others unstaged, then you could use

```
git stash pop --index
```

to try and apply them accordingly, but if there are any conflicts applying the stash, this will fail; omitting the `--index` option allows the operation to complete in this case (though you'll still have to resolve any conflicts), but it means all changes are unstaged at the end.

Since the patch does affect a file you've locally modified, it is possible you could indeed have conflicts to resolve (i.e. you modified a line that is also affected by the patch revert); this is essentially the same as a merge conflict and has to be dealt with manually on a case-by-case basis

Comment: Thanks Mark but I don't want to apply a patch I have to remove the applied patch and upon stashing and pop,the changes of the patch too get popped.

Comment: @SreejithVignesh - There is no such thing as "removing a patch".  What you want to do is apply the inverse of the previously applied patch.  Clearly you are already aware of that, since you *already tried doing it*, so I'm not sure what the problem is.